# How to query job information in CA workload automation AE (autosys)?

Tags: autosys, workload

I come to a new company, and it uses CA workload automation AE (also known as autosys) to run jobs, but there are no documentations about the configuration.
And my first step is to find out how many jobs running on the server, on which subject every job is, and how these jobs run.
I'm new to use autosys, and I learn to know it has a database to store meta data(jobs information,logs etc). But I don't know how to connect to this database.
Does someone know the default settings of this database? I guess the one who installed autosys mostly used default settings. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Unix access to it
autorep -j job_name_pattern% | wc -l;

If you are accessing via URL, when you search in QVIEW the job_name_pattern% it should list all the jobs.

Note: For each application all autosys job can / should follow same naming pattern, like starting with APP id
123_JobA
123_JobB
123_Jo

Comment: But i want to query all job details, and export them to make some matches with the applications. And i also like to write some sql statements to do some check work, that would be more flexible

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following ksh script to flatten the any JIL file and add execution status information, you can modify it to perfom any task you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

# unix scprit to flatten autorep -q

resetVar()
{
    AIF=""
    AD=""
    AH=""
    BF=""
    BN=""
    BS=""
    BT=""
    COM=""
    COD=""
    DC=""
    DOW=""
    DES=""
    EC=""
    IJ=""
    JL=""
    JT=""
    MAC=""
    MES=""
    MRA=""
    NR=""
    OWN=""
    PER=""
    PRI=""
    PRO=""
    RC=""
    RW=""
    SM=""
    ST=""
    SEF=""
    SOF=""
    TRT=""
    WF=""
    WFMS=""
    WI=""
    LSD=""
    LST=""
    LED=""
    LET=""
    STA=""
    RUN=""
}


writePartToFile()
{
 echo "$AIF;$AD;$AH;$BF;$BN;$BS;$BT;$COM;$COD;$DC;$DOW;$DES;$EC;$IJ;$JL;$JT;$MAC;$MES;$MRA;$NR;$OWN;$PER;$PRI;$PRO;$RC;$RW;$SM;$ST;$SEF;$SOF;$TRT;$WF;$WFMS;$WI" >> $TO_TPM
 #echo "$AIF;$AD;$AH;$BF;$BN;$BS;$BT;$COM;$COD;$DC;$DOW;$DES;$EC;$IJ;$JL;$JT;$MAC;$MES;$MRA;$NR;$OWN;$PER;$PRI;$PRO;$RC;$RW;$SM;$ST;$SEF;$SOF;$TRT;$WF;$WFMS;$WI" 
 resetVar

}

JOB_NAME="flatten JIL"
part1=""
part2=""


#---------------------------------
if test "$1." = "."
then
   echo "Missing first parameter (jil file to flatten)"; 
   exit 1;
fi

if test "$2." = "."
then
   echo "Missing second parameter (resulting flat file)";
 exit 1;
fi

TO_FLATTEN=$1
TO_RESULT=$2
CLE_FILE="lesCles"
CLE_TMP="lesClesTmp"
TO_TPM="tempFichier"
TO_STATUS="statusFichier"

rm $TO_RESULT
rm $CLE_TMP
rm $CLE_FILE
rm $TO_TPM
rm $TO_STATUS



echo 'alarm_if_fail;auto_delete;auto_hold;box_failure;box_name;box_success;box_terminator;command;condition;date_conditions;days_of_week;description;exclude_calendar;insert_job;job_load;job_terminator;machine;max_exit_success;max_run_alarm;n_retrys;owner;permission;priority;profile;run_calendar;run_window;start_mins;start_times;std_err_file;std_out_file;term_run_time;watch_file;watch_file_min_size;watch_interval;last_start_date;last_start_time;last_end_date;last_end_time;status;run' >> $TO_RESULT;
 while read line; do    
    if test "${line#*:}" != "$line"
    then        
      cle="$(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f 1)"
      #echo "cle = $cle"
      part2="$(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f 2)"   
      #echo "part2 = $part2"        
      val="$(echo "$part2" | cut -d" " -f 2)"
      #echo "val = $val"    
    fi  
    if test "$cle" = "insert_job"
    then
    #on n'est sur la premiere ligne
        if test "$IJ." = "."
        then
            ;                           
        else          
            if test "$BN." = "."
            then             
             echo $IJ >> $CLE_TMP
            else
             echo $BN >> $CLE_TMP
            fi      
            writePartToFile         
        fi
        IJ=$val
        JT="$(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f 3)"                   
    else    
    #on n est pas sur le premiere ligne 
        val=$part2
        case $cle in
            alarm_if_fail) AIF=$val;;
            auto_delete) AD=$val;;
            auto_hold) AH=$val;;
            box_failure) BF=$val;;
            box_name) BN=$val;;
            box_success) BS=$val;;
            box_terminator) BT=$val;;
            command) COM=$val;;
            condition) COD=$val;;
            date_conditions) DC=$val;;
            days_of_week) DOW=$val;;
            description) DES=$val;;
            exclude_calendar) EC=$val;;
            insert_job) IJ=$val;;
            job_load) JL=$val;;
            job_terminator) JT=$val;;
            machine) MAC=$val;;
            max_exit_success) MES=$val;;
            max_run_alarm) MRA==$val;;
            n_retrys) NR=$val;;
            '#owner') OWN=$val;;
            permission) PER=$val;;
            priority) PRI=$val;;
            profile) PRO=$val;;
            run_calendar) RC=$val;;
            run_window) RW=$val;;
            start_mins) SM=$val;;
            start_times) ST=$val;;
            std_err_file) SEF=$val;;
            std_out_file) SOF=$val;;
            term_run_time) TRT=$val;;
            watch_file) WF=$val;;
            watch_file_min_size) WFMS=$val;;
            watch_interval) WI=$val;; 
        esac        
    fi

done  < $TO_FLATTEN;
#Traiter derniere occurence
if test "$BN." = "."
then
    echo $IJ >> $CLE_TMP
else
    echo $BN >> $CLE_TMP
fi      
writePartToFile     

echo "Les cles"
cat $CLE_TMP | sort | uniq > $CLE_FILE
cat $CLE_FILE
rm $CLE_TMP

#------------------------------
 while read line; do        
    autorep -J ${line} -w  >> $TO_STATUS;   
done  < $CLE_FILE;
#----------------------------------------
echo " Resultats"
while read line; do
unJob="$(echo "$line" | cut -d";" -f 14)"
details="$(grep -w  "$unJob" "$TO_STATUS" | head -n 1)" 
LSD="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $2}')"
if test "$LSD" = "-----"
then
    LST=""
    LED="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $3}')"
    if test "$LED" = "-----"
    then
        LET=""
        STA="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $4}')"
        RUN="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $5}')"
    else
        LET="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $4}')"
        STA="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $5}')"
        RUN="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $6}')"
    fi
else
    LST="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $3}')"
    LED="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $4}')"
    if test "$LED" = "-----"
    then
        LET=""
        STA="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $5}')"
        RUN="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $6}')"
    else
        LET="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $5}')"
        STA="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $6}')"
        RUN="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $7}')"
    fi
fi

echo " ligne= ${line};${LSD};${LST};${LED};${LET};${STA};${RUN}"
echo "${line};${LSD};${LST};${LED};${LET};${STA};${RUN}" >> $TO_RESULT
resetVar
done  < $TO_TPM;
```

Comment: That‘s a great job! And I now use meta database to retrieve the info.
thanks a lot !